# Why do the Theano tests fail with many "KnownFailureTest"s?

Tags: python, testing, theano

Theano is failing it's tests when I do:

```
python -c "import theano; theano.test();"
```

If these are known failures, shouldn't it still pass? IE when I test other libraries, KnownFailures sometimes trigger, but the overall test still passes with "OK" (but will still note the KnownFails and Skipped tests).

My guess is this is ok, and the test really is "passing", but since I'm doing a fresh install following the deeplearning.net tutorials, and I'm getting this error, I assume others might have this question as well, and a search on Google, and SO, isn't really helpful.

Forgive the error-code-dump, I am sure no one will need to read all through this, but it's here for reference if someone else has this question. Here are the errors at the end of the tests:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_none (theano.compile.tests.test_function_module.T_function)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/compile/tests/test_function_module.py", line 42, in test_none
    raise KnownFailureTest('See #254: Using None as function output leads to [] return value')
KnownFailureTest: See #254: Using None as function output leads to [] return value

======================================================================
ERROR: test002_generator_one_scalar_output (theano.sandbox.scan_module.tests.test_scan.TestScan)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/sandbox/scan_module/tests/test_scan.py", line 474, in test002_generator_one_scalar_output
    raise KnownFailureTest('Work-in-progress sandbox ScanOp is not fully '
KnownFailureTest: Work-in-progress sandbox ScanOp is not fully functional yet

======================================================================
ERROR: test003_one_sequence_one_output_and_weights (theano.sandbox.scan_module.tests.test_scan.TestScan)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/sandbox/scan_module/tests/test_scan.py", line 512, in test003_one_sequence_one_output_and_weights
    raise KnownFailureTest('Work-in-progress sandbox ScanOp is not fully '
KnownFailureTest: Work-in-progress sandbox ScanOp is not fully functional yet

======================================================================
ERROR: test_alloc_inputs2 (theano.scan_module.tests.test_scan.T_Scan)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/scan_module/tests/test_scan.py", line 2844, in test_alloc_inputs2
    "This tests depends on an optimization for scan "
KnownFailureTest: This tests depends on an optimization for scan that has not been implemented yet.

======================================================================
ERROR: test_infershape_seq_shorter_nsteps (theano.scan_module.tests.test_scan.T_Scan)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/scan_module/tests/test_scan.py", line 3040, in test_infershape_seq_shorter_nsteps
    raise KnownFailureTest('This is a generic problem with infershape'
KnownFailureTest: This is a generic problem with infershape that has to be discussed and figured out

======================================================================
ERROR: test_outputs_info_not_typed (theano.scan_module.tests.test_scan.T_Scan)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/testing/decorators.py", line 213, in knownfailer
    raise KnownFailureTest(msg)
KnownFailureTest: This test fails because not typed outputs_info are always gived the smallest dtype. There is no upcast of outputs_info in scan for now.

======================================================================
ERROR: test_arithmetic_cast (theano.tensor.tests.test_basic.test_arithmetic_cast)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/tensor/tests/test_basic.py", line 5583, in test_arithmetic_cast
    raise KnownFailureTest('Known issue with '
KnownFailureTest: Known issue with numpy >= 1.6.x see #761

======================================================================
ERROR: test_abs_grad (theano.tensor.tests.test_complex.TestRealImag)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/testing/decorators.py", line 213, in knownfailer
    raise KnownFailureTest(msg)
KnownFailureTest: Complex grads not enabled, see #178

======================================================================
ERROR: test_complex_grads (theano.tensor.tests.test_complex.TestRealImag)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/testing/decorators.py", line 213, in knownfailer
    raise KnownFailureTest(msg)
KnownFailureTest: Complex grads not enabled, see #178

======================================================================
ERROR: test_mul_mixed (theano.tensor.tests.test_complex.TestRealImag)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/testing/decorators.py", line 213, in knownfailer
    raise KnownFailureTest(msg)
KnownFailureTest: Complex grads not enabled, see #178

======================================================================
ERROR: test_mul_mixed0 (theano.tensor.tests.test_complex.TestRealImag)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/testing/decorators.py", line 213, in knownfailer
    raise KnownFailureTest(msg)
KnownFailureTest: Complex grads not enabled, see #178

======================================================================
ERROR: test_mul_mixed1 (theano.tensor.tests.test_complex.TestRealImag)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/testing/decorators.py", line 213, in knownfailer
    raise KnownFailureTest(msg)
KnownFailureTest: Complex grads not enabled, see #178

======================================================================
ERROR: test_polar_grads (theano.tensor.tests.test_complex.TestRealImag)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/testing/decorators.py", line 213, in knownfailer
    raise KnownFailureTest(msg)
KnownFailureTest: Complex grads not enabled, see #178

======================================================================
ERROR: test_gradient (theano.tensor.tests.test_fourier.TestFourier)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/testing/decorators.py", line 213, in knownfailer
    raise KnownFailureTest(msg)
KnownFailureTest: Complex grads not enabled, see #178

======================================================================
ERROR: theano.tensor.tests.test_opt.test_log_add
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/case.py", line 197, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/tensor/tests/test_opt.py", line 1508, in test_log_add
    raise KnownFailureTest(('log(add(exp)) is not stabilized when adding '
KnownFailureTest: log(add(exp)) is not stabilized when adding more than 2 elements, see #623

======================================================================
ERROR: Currently Theano enable the constant_folding optimization before stabilization optimization.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/case.py", line 197, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/tensor/tests/test_opt.py", line 3068, in test_constant_get_stabilized
    "Theano optimizes constant before stabilization. "
KnownFailureTest: Theano optimizes constant before stabilization. This breaks stabilization optimization in some cases. See #504.

======================================================================
ERROR: test_dot (theano.tests.test_rop.test_RopLop)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/tests/test_rop.py", line 277, in test_dot
    self.check_rop_lop(tensor.dot(self.x, W), self.in_shape)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/tests/test_rop.py", line 191, in check_rop_lop
    raise KnownFailureTest("Rop doesn't handle non-differentiable "
KnownFailureTest: Rop doesn't handle non-differentiable inputs correctly. Bug exposed by fixing Add.grad method.

======================================================================
ERROR: test_elemwise0 (theano.tests.test_rop.test_RopLop)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/tests/test_rop.py", line 280, in test_elemwise0
    self.check_rop_lop((self.x + 1) ** 2, self.in_shape)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/tests/test_rop.py", line 191, in check_rop_lop
    raise KnownFailureTest("Rop doesn't handle non-differentiable "
KnownFailureTest: Rop doesn't handle non-differentiable inputs correctly. Bug exposed by fixing Add.grad method.

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2441 tests in 807.791s

FAILED (errors=18)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KnownFailureTest are a valid return value for nosetests. When Theano started, we where creating tests for features to implement and raised KnownFailureTest in them until we implement them. We do not do that anymore as we end up with to much questions from people about this. So this cause too much distraction. But we didn't changed the old tests that did that.

I just created an issue to change that: https://github.com/Theano/Theano/issues/2375

I do not know when it will be changed.